# How to make an 'OR' condition mongo node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is this how you make an or condition in mongo and node?

```
var conditions = {
$or:[
        {
            username: req.body.globalUserName,
            'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}
        },
        {
            username: req.body.globalUserName,
            'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Answer (score 1):

$or in MongoDB performs a logical **OR** on an array of expressions/conditions. see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Since `username: req.body.globalUserName` is a common denominator in your conditionals if I got you correctly, you might need **$and** operator also.

```
var conditions = {
 $and: [ 
         { username: req.body.globalUserName },
         $or: [
                 {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()},
                 {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}
              ]
        ]
}
```

Comment: this is throwing error for me on build, indicating the error is at the colon after the `$or`, error is:  `Unexpected token, expected ,`  i think the `$or` block needs to be within curly brackets too.

Answer (score 0):

-> The **$or** operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more `<expressions>` and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the `<expressions>`

-> syntax =

> `{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }`

```
var conditions = {
 $and: [ 
         { username: req.body.globalUserName },
         $or: [
                 {'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()},
                 {'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id.toString()}}
              ]
        ]
}
```

please refer to Documentation of [or in mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)